# Toggle image src on click next & prev using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to toggle the image `src` on click instead of mouseout & in.
I have multiple images,I want to toggle the image of single product, if buttons which exist in same parent div of image, will click.
Any thoughts ?

```js
function toggleImage(thisimage) {
    thisimage.toggle();
}
```

```css
.prev_btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 128%;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: dotted;
}
.next_btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 65%;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 128%;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div id="pro"><img width="206" height="260" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg'">

<div class="prev_btn" onclick="toggle(this)"></div>
<div class="next_btn" onclick="toggle(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the full HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you would do it like this.

Please give a class to your image element. Otherwise you can also toggle all image tags.

```js
$('.prev_btn, .next_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.img').toggle();
});
```

If you want to toggle all images, then just:

```js
 $('img').toggle();
```

Comment: There are multiple images & buttons on each of the images, are you sure the above code will change only the that image of which button is clicked ?

Comment: No, then of course you have to target specific elements.

That's what I said, you have to take care of which elements have to be toggled.

If you show your HTML and explain which elements, I can help you further.

Comment: @dev "there are multiple" - your question does not state or even imply this.  Terms such as "*the* image" make it look as though there is only one image.  Please update your question to clarify - eg do you have multiple images but only 1 set of next/prev or a next/prev for every image (multiple next/prev)?

Comment: I want to toggle the image of single product, if buttons which exist in same parent div of image, will click.

Comment: @dev please edit the question to include this, possibly with additional HTML to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.prev_btn, .next_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  var this$ = $(e.currentTarget), // grab the currently clicked button element
    parent$ = this$.parents('#pro').first(), // grab the parent of the button that has the id #pro
    contextBasedImgs$ = parent$.find('img'); // grab all the images in the parent div with id #pro


  contextBasedImgs$.each(function(ignore, el) {
    var currEl$ = $(el),
      newURI = currEl$.attr('onmouseout');

    currEl$.attr('src', newURI);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but you've used static url of image in   contextBasedImgs$.attr('src', 'https://www.newsource.de/img.png');

Comment: Just have a look at my new answer above @dev.

Comment: Some js error is their, can you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

First, move your images into an array on a `data-` attribute on the image itself - this gives you different set of images and any number of images - rather than just toggle between two, which you don't need next *and* previous buttons, so the implication is that you want more than two images.

```
<img data-images='["https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg","https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"]' ...
```

Next, use js/jquery event handlers rather than HTML `onclick=` just gives you more control and separation of html/code etc (see other SO questions for more info)

```
$(".prev_btn").click(function() {
```

Within this handler, we find the relevant image using your parent wrapper.  Here I've given the wrapper a `class` rather than an `id` so that you can have multiple wrappers without needing different IDs and easier to style in css (rather than `.closest("div")`)

```
$(this).closest(".wrapper").find("img").first()
```

and the click event handler calls a common method with the direction (rather than repeat all the same code)

This stores on each image the current index so no need for additional variables to "remember"

```
img.data("index", new_index);
```

Then it's a case of reading the array from the image, changing the index based on direction and updating the image.

I've had to make some tweaks to your CSS for the buttons (just for demo) and the 2nd image includes a 3rd image url to show it working with more than just toggle

```js
$(".prev_btn").click(function() {
    changeImage($(this).closest(".wrapper").find("img").first(), -1)
});
$(".next_btn").click(function() {
    changeImage($(this).closest(".wrapper").find("img").first(), 1)
});

function changeImage(img, direction)
{
    var images = img.data("images");
    var idx = img.data("index");
    
    idx += direction;
    if (idx >= images.length) idx = 0;
    if (idx < 0) idx = images.length - 1;
    
    img
      .data("index", idx)
      .attr("src", images[idx]);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}

.prev_btn, .next_btn {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 255px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-style: dotted;
}

.next_btn {
  left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img width="206" height="260" 
       src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" 
       data-images='["https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg","https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"]'
       data-index="1">
  <div class="prev_btn"></div>
  <div class="next_btn"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img width="206" height="260" 
       src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" 
       data-images='["https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg","https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg", "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"]'
       data-index="0">
  <div class="prev_btn"></div>
  <div class="next_btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks great, it can't be done without "data" attribute, as its not possible for me to change html.

Comment: You've said elsewhere you want different images for each img (not static in the code) - how are you specifying those images?

Comment: Are you also saying that you can't remove the `onmouseover="this.src='`?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused because `onmouseover=` *is* html just as `data-images=` is html.  But no matter - how are you specifying the src= list for each image?